# Using Regexp to get information in a KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, regex

Help me to parse this message:

```
text=&direction=re&orfo=rus&files_id=&message=48l16qL2&old_charset=utf-8&template_id=&HTMLMessage=1&draft_msg=&re_msg=&fwd_msg=&RealName=0&To=john+%3Cjohn11%40gmail.com%3E&CC=&BCC=&Subject=TestSubject&Body=%3Cp%3EHello+%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&secur
```

I would like to get information in an KeyValuePair:
**Key - Value**
text -
direction - re
and so on.
And how to convert this: `Hello+%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%...`
there are cyrillic character.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that this is your first time encountering a query string and URL-encoded characters. Well, good news: you don't need a regex to parse this.

Comment: BoltClock: are you recommend to use Split?

Comment: @Irima: Use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a Regex, you can do it like this:

```
// I only added the first 3 keys, but the others are basically the same
Regex r = new Regex(@"text=(?<text>.*)&direction=(?<direction>.*)&orfo=(?<orfo>.*)");
Match m = r.Match(inputText);

if(m.Success)
{
    var text = m.Groups["text"].Value; // result is ""
    var direction = m.Groups["direction"].Value; // re
    var orfo = m.Groups["orfo"].Value;
}
```

However, the method suggested by BoltClock is **much better**:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection = 
    System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(inputString);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are dealing with a URI,   better to use the proper class than try and figure out the detailed processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx